# Matrix derivatives for quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to figure out how to compute derivatives for the following:

Consider

\begin{equation}
\left[ N^{-1} Z' \left( y - X \beta \right) \right]^{'} W_N \left[  N^{-1} Z' \left( y - X \beta \right) \right]
\end{equation}

where $N$ is a scalar, $Z$ is an $N \times L$ matrix, $X$ is an $N \times K$ matrix, with $L \ge K$, $y$ is a column vector of size $n$ and $W_N$ is an $L \times L$ positive definite symmetric matrix.

I should differentiate with respect to $\beta$ and get

\begin{equation}
\beta = (X'ZW_NZ'X)^{-1} X'ZW_N Z'y
\end{equation}

Can you kindly spell out the steps to get $\beta$?